# declare a pointer from user class inside bison (yacc.y file)

Tags: c++, nested-class, bisonc++

i'm working on a compiler project for python syntax but adding a new features like inheritance and object oriented Concepts .. so i have a class a like:

```
class a {
   public:
      class b{};
};
```

and i want to declare a pointer from class b inside the bison so i write before yacc grammer this:

```
 %union{
    class a::b *pointer;
}
```

but it shows this error when i run it :

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

error C2838: 'b' : illegal qualified name in member declaration

please help !